# Incorrect redirect on homepage load

Tags: magento2.3, redirect, home-page

On a fresh Magento 2 Open Source install, I accidentally named the site "foo.locale" instead of "foo.local". I've updated the database with the correct value [1] but when accessing the homepage `foo.local` I am still getting redirected to `foo.locale` with a parameter:

```
$ curl -I http://foo.local
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://foo.locale/?SID=ltpekiq86h9nltd5rhgdeaidav
```

I have used `mysqldump` to confirm that the string `foo.locale` is not found anywhere in the database, and I've used `grep` to confirm that the string is not found in any files either.

**Where is the redirect happening, and how can I prevent it?**

[1] Changing "foo.locale" to "foo.local" in the database:

```
MariaDB> update core_config_data set value='http://foo.local/' where value='http://foo.locale/';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

MariaDB> update core_config_data set value='https://foo.local/' where value='https://foo.locale/';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: have you cleared cache, after update?

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I would still like to know where this information was stored, though, if not in the database nor in the files.

Comment: It stored in magento cache: var/cache directory.

Comment: Thank you Jignesh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to clear the cache.

You can clear cache using admin:

```
> System > Cache Management
```

Also, You can use command to clear cache:

- Open the terminal and run below command:

> `php bin/magento c:f && php bin/magento c:c`

If it helps you, please accept it as a solution.

Comment: Thank you Jignesh. The CLI commands worked.